# Возможность отследить появление новой записи в MySQL

Tags: mysql, golang

меня интересует то, каким образом можно бы было отследить появление новой записи в базе данных и есть ли вообще такая возможность.

В тегах указал Golang не потому что вопрос касается какой-то его составляющей, а потому что реализация необходима под него.

В стандартной либе db/sql ничего подобного в методах не смог отыскать.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это все дело мониторить.

Comment: На сервере - триггер, пишущий в служебную таблицу, на клиенте - периодический опрос этой таблицы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в самой БД установить тригер на все CRUD операции:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
    AFTER INSERT
    ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- statements
END$$    

DELIMITER ;
```

Больше по ссылке
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/